# How to pipe multiple values to a C program, with python -c

Tags: python, terminal, pipe

So, I know I can pipe a value, with python, to the stdin of a C program:

```
python -c 'print "Hello"' | ./program
```

The 'Hello' string will be read by the first scanf of the C program (or similar function).

My problem is, how do I do this when I have multiple scanfs and I want to pass individual values to each one of them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same manner you can do this. 
Suppose your C program take a string first and then two integer.

So you separate the input value by `\n` as you would do in a terminal, like:

```
python -c 'print "Hello\n5 10"' | ./program
```